# Android errors throughout project

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got a project from Github, that I'm viewing in Android Studio (3.0 Preview). When I build the project I get 0 errors but when I'm viewing the projects files, I get a lot of errors about not matching Class types.

Examples

> Wrong 1st argument type Found 'android.support.v7.appCompatActivity' expected 'android.App.Activity'

on

```
Utils.patchFiles(outerClass, TAG,
                    new Utils.DesiredFilesKeywordGetter(), type2files);
```

> Cannot resolve method startActivity(android.content.Intent)

on

```
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even I had the same problem once.

In your android studio gp to

**File ->Invalidate Cashes / Restart**

Then **Clean** and **Rebuild** the app again.
Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm